# Java: Creating a 2D array from a text file/missing data

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I tried to create a 2D array using the numbers in the text file below but it seems that I can't create the last 2 rows of my 2D array.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        File inFile = new File(name);

        int[][] table2 = reading(inFile);

        printTable(table2);     
        System.out.println();
    }       

    // scanning file
    public static int[][] reading(File inFile) {
        //Create the input stream.
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(inFile); // doesn't connect
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found! Program will now exit!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int i = 2;
        int row = in.nextInt(); //reading the first integer for row
        int col = in.nextInt(); //reading the first integer for column  
        int[][] data = new int[row][col]; 

        System.out.println("row is " + row + " and col is " + col); 

        // turn data into array 
        while(in.hasNext() && i < data.length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
                data[i-2][j] = in.nextInt();
            }
            i++;
        }
        return data;    
    }

    // display 2D array
    public static void printTable(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0 ; row < matrix.length ; row++) {
            for (int col = 0 ; col < matrix[row].length ; col++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the text file. The first 2 numbers are the number of rows and columns

```
5
6
5
15
8
5
3
16
9
14
12
14
20
4
17
11
11
11
20
14
16
5
18
12
10
19
17
11
10
2
16
20
```

Comment: Why do you initialize `i=2` instead of `i=0`?

Comment: Wow, I thought I need to skip 2 numbers. Actually I don't have to. Thank you.